# Extending Application to share variables globally

Tags: android, global-variables

I'm trying to share two ArrayLists across the various activities in my application, using the scheme explained here: [How to declare global variables in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables).

Here's my application subclass:

```
public class GlobalVars extends Application{
 ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>(); 
  ArrayList<String> playerNames = new ArrayList<String>();

  public ArrayList<Player> getPlayers(){
   return players;
  }

  public ArrayList<String> getPlayerNames(){
   return playerNames;
  }

  public void setPlayers(ArrayList<Player> p){
   players = p;
  }

  public void setPlayerNames(ArrayList<String> pn){
   playerNames = pn;
  }

}
```

And used the code:

```
 GlobalVars gv = (GlobalVars)getApplicationContext();
        players = gv.getPlayers();
        playerNames = gv.getPlayerNames();
```

To access these variables. The first line there where I define gv throws a classcastexception. Anyone know why?

Here's the code I added to the manifest:

```
<application android:name="com.myname.GlobalVars"
 android:icon="@drawable/icon"
 android:label="@string/app_name"></application>
```

edit:for clarification, here is my entire manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myname.bpstattracker" android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".BPStatTracker" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".BPSTAdd"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".OneOrThree"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".SixOrTen"></activity>

    </application>


    <application android:name="com.myname.GlobalVars"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: You have `<application>` defined twice in your manifest.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To elaborate on Peter K's answer, you do not need to create a second `<application>` section for your derived Application class.  You simply need to "rename" your existing `<application>` section by amending it with the `android:name` tag.  I also want to point out that the fully qualified classname is required(as you've done correctly...I found this out the hard way).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myname.bpstattracker" android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:name="com.myname.GlobalVars" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".BPStatTracker" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".BPSTAdd"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".OneOrThree"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".SixOrTen"></activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Some times you will need to implement it in several places in The Manifest:
<application
        android:name="com.example.MyAppClass"
        android:allowBackup="true">
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.MyAppClass"
            android:configChanges="locale"
            android:label="MyAppClass" >
            <action android:name="com.example.MyAppClass" />
        </activity>

Answer (score 9):

To be clear,

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_app"
    android:label="@string/app_title"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
```

Is my existing manifest. To declare another application within my existing manifest, and or app all together, i would simply add:

```
android:name="com.XXXXXX.data.DataStore"
```

So the end result will be:

```
<application
    android:name="com.XXXXXX.data.DataStore" *<-- class that extends Application and has global variables with exact package and class name*
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_app"
    android:label="@string/app_title"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
```

Comment: Thats the trick, funny how many people are asking this question, and this was the only truley clear awnser. Thank you Barneco

Answer (score 5):

You should call `getApplication()` in your Activity or Service:

```
GlobalVars gv = (GlobalVars)getApplication();
```

**Edit:**

You have `<application>` defined twice in your manifest.

Comment: The first application tag and all of the things inside of it were auto-generated by Eclipse. If I change the first application to give it a new name/label/icon won't it completely screw up the way my program runs?

Comment: Changing name/label/icon will not "screw up the way program runs".