# May mainting the session using Shared preference in android

Tags: android, session, sharedpreferences

Hi i want to maintain some sessions in my application. May i use shared preference to maintain it? I not then plz suggest me the proper way with the simple example.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572338/extending-application-to-share-variables-globally

Comment: Yes, this is a good place to store data.

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe you should make use of server to maintain sessions**. Because as you have suggested here, using shared preference, you are leaving the option of clearing the preferences from memory to the user. So in this case if the user clears your app data, then your concept of sessions fails.

Comment: If a user clears the app data they can expect to be logged out.

Comment: So what is the simple way to do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the shared preferences.

For example, to save username, password and session ID, you can:

```
SharedPreferences pref = myContexy.getSharedPreferences("Session Data", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
edit.putString("User Name", username);
edit.putString("Password", password);
edit.putInt("Session ID", session_id);
edit.commit();
```

And to get them:

```
SharedPreferences pref = myContexy.getSharedPreferences("Session Data", MODE_PRIVATE);
username = pref.getString("User Name", "");
password = pref.getString("Password", "");
session_id = pref.getInt("Session ID", 0);
```

This is just an example, it is better to use string constants instead of just "User Name" etc.

Comment: It depends on you, I just gave an example of how to use shared preferences, maybe you don't need session_id at all...

Comment: Actually as of my knowledge session id's value is generating by itself. Is it true???

Comment: And ya in this example do i need to give session_id statically.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking [onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29). It can be used to save the state of a page and restore it later