# Shared session over several apps (not activities!)

Tags: android, session, sharing

I'd like to share data "globally" between **applications** (not activities). The problem is, I have several applications that need to have only on user session: say you log in to one app and if you open another app it won't ask for you to log in again, but will "remember" your id, and that you are logged in.

I have found [this solution using the SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572338/extending-application-to-share-variables-globally?lq=1).

The apps, I'm talking about won't be on Google Play so theoretically this approach could work, I am however worried that someone could just write a rogue app and set the id in the AndroidManifest.xml and have access to all other apps without authentication (I'm writing enterprise apps, so this could be a serious security breach).

Another possible approach would be to have a separate app only for logging in and storing sessions, that all other apps access with intents... this however seems very messy for several reasons (life-cycle, etc.)

Any thoughts / alternatives?

Comment: you can use save session on server,every time app start check on server for user session

Comment: @ Iftikar Urrhman Khan - I'll be using a RESTful server, and would try to avoid the handling of session on server-side altogether if possible.