# Multiple <application> tags in manifest file

Tags: android, android-manifest

I want to add another project to my app. But it uses its own "application tag" in AndroidManifest file. And one of its class **extends Application**

So the problem is I use my own "application" preferences. How can I integrate this new project's "application" preferences to mine ? Will I change somethings on "class **extends Application**" ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity android:name="com.my.other.project.package.name.MyClassName">
```

by this you could add your other project activity.

**Only the `<manifest>` and `<application>` elements are required, they each must be present and can occur only once.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.animal.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="myOtherPackageName.MyClassName"/> // here where you put your other package name.
</application>
```

Comment: Thanks, so I will put <application > preferences in to <activity> and  `Class extends Application` will be `extends Activity` am I right ?

Comment: I understand this part; But there is a `sampleclass extends Application` and in `onCrate` it uses `getApplicationContext()` ... So if I use <activity> instead of <application> , which changes must I make in sampleclass ?

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572338/extending-application-to-share-variables-globally

Comment: Some times you will need to implement it in several places in The Manifest:
<application
        android:name="com.example.MyAppClass"
        android:allowBackup="true">
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.MyAppClass"
            android:configChanges="locale"
            android:label="MyAppClass" >
            <action android:name="com.example.MyAppClass" />
        </activity>