# Cannot instantiate class in Android App

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an Android app. In my app, I lanuch an Intent to another class. As soon as this happens, the app crashes. It says that it can't instantiate my class. My code is below:

```
public class CustomObject extends Activity{
ArrayList<String> Alerts;
ArrayList<String> Names;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Intent intent = getIntent();
Names = intent.getExtras().getStringArrayList("Names");
Alerts = intent.getExtras().getStringArrayList("Alerts");
}


public CustomObject(ArrayList<String> prop1, ArrayList<String> prop2) {
    this.Names = prop1;
    this.Alerts = prop2;
}

public ArrayList<String> getProp1() {
    return Names;
}

public ArrayList<String> getProp2() {
   return Alerts;
}
}
```

Here's my LogCat:

```
10-24 19:56:25.234: E/AndroidRuntime(12982): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-24 19:56:25.234: E/AndroidRuntime(12982): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.dev.chicagotraintracker/com.dev.chicagotraintracker.CustomObject}: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.dev.chicagotraintracker.CustomObject; no empty constructor
10-24 19:56:25.234: E/AndroidRuntime(12982):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
10-24 19:56:25.234: E/AndroidRuntime(12982):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
10-24 19:56:25.234: E/AndroidRuntime(12982):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-24 19:56:25.234: E/AndroidRuntime(12982):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
10-24 19:56:25.234: E/AndroidRuntime(12982):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-24 19:56:25.234: E/AndroidRuntime(12982):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-24 19:56:25.234: E/AndroidRuntime(12982):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-24 19:56:25.234: E/AndroidRuntime(12982):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-24 19:56:25.234: E/AndroidRuntime(12982):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-24 19:56:25.234: E/AndroidRuntime(12982):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-24 19:56:25.234: E/AndroidRuntime(12982):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-24 19:56:25.234: E/AndroidRuntime(12982):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-24 19:56:25.234: E/AndroidRuntime(12982): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.dev.chicagotraintracker.CustomObject; no empty constructor
10-24 19:56:25.234: E/AndroidRuntime(12982):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
10-24 19:56:25.234: E/AndroidRuntime(12982):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
10-24 19:56:25.234: E/AndroidRuntime(12982):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
10-24 19:56:25.234: E/AndroidRuntime(12982):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
10-24 19:56:25.234: E/AndroidRuntime(12982):    ... 11 more
```

I can't find the problem in my code. Some other questions have said something about a no-argument constructor, but how do I implement that? Is that even my problem? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Not having a `no-argument constructor` is EXACTLY your problem.  Did you read your logcat, or just C&P here for us to read for you?  `Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.dev.chicagotraintracker.CustomObject; no empty constructor`

Comment: I saw what it said, I just don't understand what a no-argument constructor is and what the exact problem with my code is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activities and Fragments **may not** have constructors with parameters (a.k.a. arguments), like this one:

```
public CustomObject(ArrayList<String> prop1, ArrayList<String> prop2) {
    this.Names = prop1;
    this.Alerts = prop2;
}
```

Only a constructor with no parameters is allowed `public CustomObject() {` (you don't need to specify a constructor at all)

You will have to pass that info in the `Intent` using a String array. See [putExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d%29) and [getStringArrayExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringArrayExtra%28java.lang.String%29)

To create this intent from another Activity, you can use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, CustomObject.class);
intent.putExtra("prop1", arrayList.toArray(new String[arrayList.size()]));
intent.putExtra("prop2", arrayList2.toArray(new String[arrayList2.size()]));
startActivity(intent);
```

And then in the `onCreate` method of your Activity, you can retrieve the values using:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(intent.getStringArrayExtra("prop1")));
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(intent.getStringArrayExtra("prop2")));
```

Because it's not possible to send a `List` over an intent that easily, here it is turned to a String array and then turned back to a List in the onCreate method.

Comment: How would I create that intent? What would the class be?

Comment: Is there any way to pass that ArrayList to another class without an Intent? I don't want it to ever display the class I have above, I just want to pass the data to that class from the UI class, then pass it to another, then pass it back to the UI class.

Comment: @hichris123 It is possible to "pass" (or rather store) any object through the `Application` object, [read here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572338/extending-application-to-share-variables-globally) for more info about that

Answer (score 0):

Class that inherit `Activity` class or `Fragment` ***MUST*** have empty constructor. Do some reading on this.

In your current situation you might try to workaround it by keeping this argumented constructor and call `super()`, note: this is empty super class constructor call.

I don't like this approach. Simon's solution by sending through intent is right way to do this.

Comment: A call to `super()` is inserted implicitly by Java. That would not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Activity needs a non-argument constructor.Now,you added a constructor with two arguments.So,you also should add a non-constructor:

```
public CustomObject(){
}
```