# Android Header? How to create enums visible in whole project?

Tags: android, enums

I'm looking for a way to create a "header" or something like that to specify some variables like:

```
enum Misc
{
    double EFFECT_DAMAGE = Math.pow(2,0);
    double EFFECT_ABSORB = Math.pow(2,1);
    double EFFECT_HEAL   = Math.pow(2,2);
    int SPELL_FIREBALL   = 51673;
}
```

And in every .java file I want to be able to write:

```
double effect = 1;
if (effect == EFFECT)
{
    ...some code...
}
```

Is there a nice way to do this?
I'm creating a mini game for now and want to have all the files nice and tidy to manage my project in the future easier once it gets bigger.

Thx in advance.

Comment: Extend `Application` and put the enum in there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572338/extending-application-to-share-variables-globally

Comment: Can I know why my answer using Enum as you wished did not satisfy you?

Comment: Your code was nice. I used it first but later I wanted to use the code in a switch and with your code I got a problem that its a bad type and stuff like that and I switched to sergiomse answer and it works good too + it works in switches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assign values this way to a enum in java.

Instead you should use a public class with public static final variables to make them constants.

```
public class Misc {
    public static final double EFFECT_DAMAGE = Math.pow(2,0);
    public static final double EFFECT_ABSORB = Math.pow(2,1);
    public static final double EFFECT_HEAL   = Math.pow(2,2);
    public static final int SPELL_FIREBALL   = 51673;
}
```

So you can use in your code like

```
if (effect == Misc.EFFECT_DAMAGE )
{
    ...some code...
}
```

If you want use only the field without the class name first you should import the class as static:

```
import static test.Misc.*;

....

if (effect == EFFECT_DAMAGE ) {
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public enum Misc 
{
    EFFECT_DAMAGE(0), // 2^0
    EFFECT_ABSORB(1), // 2^1
    FIREBALL(245151);

    private double value;

    private Misc(double d){
        value = d;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return String.valueOf(value);
    }
}
```

Access like this:

```
System.out.println("Fireball damage:" + Misc.FIREBALL);
```