# How to save object in memory for all activity\ies when application is alive, Android

Tags: android, caching, memcached, retrofit, rx-java

I have an app, it uses Rxjava and Retrofit to retrieve data from backend.

after login, I will get a JSON file which includes User information (name, email, id, stripeId....). I will need to use User information when retrieving data from backend in other activities. Since there are many times I need to use the User information, saving it in Database or SharePreference may spend a lot of time.

Is there any way that I can save the data in the memory when the App is alive (not killed in the background)? Thanks first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend Application Class which is initiated on application startup. 
Check it here:

[Extending Application to share variables globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572338/extending-application-to-share-variables-globally)